# Pass current SSO user to WorkItemTrackingHttpClient

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an MVC .NET 5 webapp that authenticates with the default VS SSO template to our company AD. I need this app to connect to *Azure DevOps* using the current logged in user to read/update tickets.

How can I instantiate a `VssCredential` from the current `User` to pass to the `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` constructor so that users can only read/update tickets they already have access to?

Comment: You will have to implement an OAuth authentication flow for this. Refer to the documentation for examples.

Comment: Which documentation? I'm new web development and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: The documentation for the Azure DevOps library.

Comment: Oh, that one I already went through but all the examples in it (plus anything else I found on the web) are authenticated with a PAT token using a `VssBasicCredential`. This is inconvenient because the user could potentially have access to tickets that his account doesn't have access to. Is there anything in particular you could send me for OAuth authentication flow?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops#samples